# How can I apply a function to vectors inside a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have a function `f(vec)` which takes as input a vector (array) of size 3.  I have a matrix `M` of size `100 x 100 x 3`.  Is there a way I can somehow apply `f` to every cell of M, outputting a matrix `N` of size `100 x 100`?  For example, `N(10,20)` would equal

```
f( M(10,20,1), M(10,20,2), M(10,20,3) )
```

Obviously I could use a for loop, but I feel like this should be vectorizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vectorization in this context means rewriting the function in a way that it accepts multiple inputs at once. Assuming that this is not possible, a for loop is the best possibility.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is `arrayfun`

```
arrayfun(@(x,y,z) f(x,y,z), M(10,20,1), M(10,20,2), M(10,20,3) , 'uni', 0)
```

Comment: Note that using `arrayfun` isn't vectorisation, it's basically equivalent to using a `for` loop.